# Capturing values from url in post request in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to capture url values from a url into my views in a post request.

My urls.py looks like below

from django.urls import path
from . import views as projects_views

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:project_id>/comments', projects_views.ProjectCommentList.as_view(), name="project_comments"),
]
```

and I want to capture the value `project_id` in my ListCreateAPIView.
Get call works fine.

My views.py looks like below

```
class ProjectCommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = projects_models.Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = projects_serializers.CommentSerializer


    def get(self, request, project_id=None):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        queryset = queryset.filter(project__id=project_id)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        project_id = ###  Need "project_id" here
        project = projects_models.Project.objects.get(id=data.get('project_id'))
        serializer.save(project=project)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Write a [`post`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) method like you did for `get`?

Comment: No, it still doesn't capture the value :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`self.kwargs["project_id"]`** to get the **`project_id`** in **`perform_create()`** method,

```
class ProjectCommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        project_id = self.kwargs["project_id"]
        project = projects_models.Project.objects.get(id=data.get('project_id'))
        serializer.save(project=project)
```

Comment: also, the request url?

Comment: i haven't separately declared the post method, i am using the same provided with ListCreateApiView, my request url is of the format `/123/comments` where i create a comment for the post with id 123.

Comment: whats the result of **`print("self.kwargs")`**?

Comment: For me if is replace (self, serializer) from the parameters of perform_create to (self, *args, **kwargs) I get the received kwargs as `{}` but self.kwargs has the value I was looking for, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Create a scope varibale in your get method for the same class using "self"

```
def get(self, request, project_id=None):
        ...
        self.project_id = project_id
        ...

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        ...
        project_id = self.project_id OR q = ExampleQuery.filter(project_id=self.project_id)
        ...
```

Comment: i'm not sure if it'll work, as when we're doing a post call I don't think the get will be called so the self.project_id will not be set.

Comment: If you are using a post call, then you can add self.project_id =  project_id in post() as well. I am assuming,  you are just using get()

Comment: No, my issue was where I can get the project_id from my url, I got the answer, its there in the self.kwargs . I am using both post and get.

Answer (score 1):

`self.kwargs` contains the all keyword arguments provided in url path. so, we can access the `project_id` like `self.kwargs['project_id']`. Use a print statement like `print(self.kwargs)` to know what actually `self.kwargs` has.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    # ... your code
    project_id = self.kwargs['project_id']
    # ... your code
```